# Your app contains NSUserTrackingUsageDescription, indicating that you will request permission to track users

Tags: swift, admob

I have added Google Admob framework for showing ads in app and getting the error related to User Tracking Usage in itunes connect app privacy section. iTunesConnect is not allowing to submit the app.
After that i have the proper key and description in info.plist.

```
<key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
<string>App would like to access IDFA for tracking purpose</string>
```

And also added code for requesting permission in login page and called it in viewDidLoad.

```
    func requestPermission() {
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { status in
            switch status {
            case .authorized:
                // Tracking authorization dialog was shown
                // and we are authorized
                print("Authorized")
                
                // Now that we are authorized we can get the IDFA
                print(ASIdentifierManager.shared().advertisingIdentifier)
            case .denied:
                // Tracking authorization dialog was
                // shown and permission is denied
                print("Denied")
            case .notDetermined:
                // Tracking authorization dialog has not been shown
                print("Not Determined")
            case .restricted:
                print("Restricted")
            @unknown default:
                print("Unknown")
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}
```

**But Still error is not going from iTunesConnect after uploading the new build, I'm not able to submit build.
Any one has faced the same thing ?
How this error will be hide>**

[image]

Comment: Have you updated the new Privacy "Product Page Preview"? it is the new short privacy policy thing. It sounds like you need to update it. Since your "Publish" button is disabled I would assume that you haven't done that. It will say "Published XX days ago by XXXX"

Comment: Yes @loremipsum bro that is also updated, Please see updated whole screenshot for privacy section and still publish button is not enable.

Comment: You are saying that data is not collected but at the same time you are using the IDFA. That is collecting. You might not be getting the IDFA yourself but AdMob is. You have to answer your privacy to be in accordance with AdMob Privacy Policy. Your UsageDescription also says tracking but your privacy policy says no, the is a disconnect. You are responsible for anything AdMob does.

Comment: You might want to double-check if your app includes a Mac version.  Even though it was turned off in my app, I found it enabled in the Pods Targets.

Comment: Thanks @loremipsum, I have changed privacy section and selection the device ID and third party advertising section now i am able to submit build.

Comment: how you fix it?

Comment: You have to go App privacy and modify that accordingly

Answer (score 9):

You only need to use the NSUserTrackingUsageDescription property in the info.plist if you are collecting user data for Advertising and/or Third-Party libraries.

If you keep the information within your app, or for authentication purposes, you are not Tracking; therefore, you do not need this property. (I hope I've interpreted this correctly.)

In other words, the information you provided in the App Privacy section of App Store Connect, is inconsistent with the NSUserTrackingUsageDescription property in the info.plist.

Comment: Thank you for this information but how is anyone meant to know this? I've been battling with the disabled publish button for hours. Do you have a link to any documentation which lists the above?

Comment: UPDATE: The solution for me was to go back and uncheck all options then add them back one at a time for which data we collect.

Comment: thats a good information. Confusion here is; is Firebase Analytics and Crashes information by logging Users phone information etc are considered tracking?

Answer (score 5):

The issue is due to how the "App Privacy" section is set up. Based on your choices, it has determined that you are not collecting any data.

This is false because you are using IDFA (advertising identifier) so you are collecting "identifiers."

**You need to revisit the "App Privacy" and modify your choices.**

Answer (score 4):

I get the similar error, "Your app contains NSUserTrackingUsageDescription, indicating that you will request permission to track users.".

I removed the NSUserTrackingUsageDescription from the info.plist file, and the UMP lib in a new build and everything related.

And all the Admob requests have    [GADMobileAds.sharedInstance.requestConfiguration tagForChildDirectedTreatment:YES];

But Appstoreconnect keeps giving the same error. Seems like appsstoreconnect is checking all the builds even when they are not used.

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to this? I'm having a similar issue where the already released version of the app uses NSUserTrackingUsageDescription, but the new version I'm trying to release does not. App Privacy cannot be updated as it says I'm still using that key.

Comment: No i do not have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when i selected "NO" on the Data collection questionnaire.

Even you are not collecting data for yourself, Google will collect the data for their admob advertising purposes. **For resolve this error, you must edit the Data collection questionnaire and select "YES".**

[image]

More than that, you must indicate more specifically what data you are collecting. Apple has announced data disclosure requirements will be required for new apps and app updates starting December 8, 2020.

For this issue, Google Admob provided a [statement](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/data-disclosure). But this statement is vague. It doesn't give the questionnaire answers. So searched and found an article that clearly give the solution for my issue. Refer the [Michael Kiley's Medium Article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/filling-out-the-app-privacy-section-in-app-store-connect-for-admob-users-bca0768ad86e) and Fill the questionnaires.